# IIS 8 Can't see partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When doing a post to a partial view, locally the visual studio web-server recognizes the view and runs the method but when running from IIS8 server it gives me a 404 can't find page error.

In my code behind on the Home controller I have this function

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Void UpdateUserSystem(bool isChecked, int SystemId, int UserID)
    {
        // if isChecked then add system to user in the UserSystems table else remove it.

        UserSystemBI usBI = new UserSystemBI();

        if (isChecked)
            usBI.InsertUserSystem(UserID, SystemId);
        else
            usBI.DeleteUserSystem(UserID, SystemId);
    }
```

I'm also sending in an ajax post to `http://dalwindev03/Home/UpdateUserSystem?SystemId=4&UserID=5&isChecked=false`

When I do this on the dalwindev03 server it simply can't find the UpdateUserSystem 'view', but locally when going to the same url (`http://localhost:10127/Home/UpdateUserSystem?SystemId=4&UserID=5&isChecked=false`)  it has no issue and hits that function and runs the code.

What the heck am I missing?

Comment: How are you publishing/deploying the site to the web server?

Comment: I'm doing build->publish to a local folder and then copying and pasting to web-server application directory.  Everything else is working including some ajax on another page.

Comment: What does your View look like?  Is the Submit button inside the partial or the main?  You may need to look into EditorTemplates instead of Partials.  Are you using Partial or RenderPartial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this issue when the build action of the file you're attempting to deploy is set to 'None' instead of 'Content'. In the Solution Explorer, open the properties of the view that is missing. Ensure that 'Build Action' is set to 'Content'.

Here's the properties window I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: That wasn't it, I just figured it out...it was pretty silly.  On the webserver I need to spell out the application name, so instead of http://dalwindev03/Home/UpdateUserSystem?SystemId=4&UserID=5&isChecked=false

it should be 
http://dalwindev03/SystemUptime/Home/UpdateUserSystem?SystemId=4&UserID=5&isChecked=false

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that 'Build Action' is set to 'Content'. This line is very helpful. After 4 days wasting get this & solved my problem.