# window.onload with querystring Not working on deployed MVC6 project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10

I have been developing a website that can display some data. In the table, there is a button in each row to open a new window, where the user can see data related to that line.

I am using MVC 6 and I used Javascript to open the window and passing the 'id' parameter through querystring.

My code is:

The Parent View .cshtml:

The Button:

```
wButtonClass = "btn btn-warning openW"; 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="@wButtonClass" data-id=@id.ToString()>@buttonText</a>
```

The Script:

```
<script>       
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".openW").click(function (e) {    
                var x = $(this).data("id"); 
                var new_window = window.open('/MyView/HandleButton?id='+x, '_blank', 'left=200,top=150,width=1000,height=800,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
  });
});
</script>
```

The Controller:

```
public IActionResult HandleButton(int id)
{
            
//Filling the List

return PartialView("DataView", myList);
}
```

So, it is working just fine from VS, but when I deploy the project to an IIS server (not on my machine), it opens the new window, and says "404 - Not Found", although the URL in the newly opened window is correct (the value is passed)

What could be the problem?

I've been looking through several forum questions, but couldn't find an answer.

**Update 1:**

Well, technicalliy, in the popup window, the URL is:
http://localhost/MyView/HandleButton?id=5
And it says in the 404 Error Details:
Requested URL http://localhost:80/MyView/HandleButton?id=5
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyView\HandleButton

**Update 2:**

Well, I have finally found an answer. It looks very silly, but solved the problem.
I found it here:
[IIS 8 Can't see partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866114/iis-8-cant-see-partial-view)

I had to change the URL and add the application name:
So, instead of: `/MyView/HandleButton?id='+x`
I Typed: `/MyWebApp/MyView/HandleButton?id='+x`

Well, it works on the server, but doesn't work in VS. It will be fine (I just change the URL everytime I debug), but is there a way to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score -1):

This could be expected if the routing is incorrect and the URL is incorrect. However, since your URL is correct and you still seeing a 404 error, it likely is an issue with the server configuration.

- Verify that the IIS server has the correct permissions to access the
  files and folders of your application.
- Check that the IIS server has the correct .NET Framework version
  installed and that your application is targeting the correct version.
- Make sure that the IIS server has the correct MVC version installed
  and that your application is targeting the correct version.
- Check that the IIS server is configured to handle requests to the
  .cshtml files.
- Make sure that the MVC routing is configured correctly in the
  web.config file of your application.
- Check whether the IIS server is running in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.
  Make sure that your application is built for the same mode.
- Confirm that the server is able to find the DLLs and assemblies that
  your application needs.
- Check the event logs for any info.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it, but you sound like ChatGPT :D